# Regex: 1 characters 8 numbers

Tags: regex

I thought this regular expression would work:

```
preg_match("/^e[a-z]i\d{7}$/", $_POST['username'])
```

I'm trying to validate a user's login credentials to match the following format:

e00123456

The 'e' can be either e or E and the 8 numbers after the 'e' can be any number ranging from 0-9. But it has to be the letter 'e' followed by 8 numbers, no more, no less. What's wrong with my regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're currently matching:

1. `^`: From the start
2. `e`: find an `e`
3. `[a-z]`: then one character which is in `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxzy`
4. `i`: followed by an `i`
5. `\d{7}`: followed by seven digits
6. `$`: And only match if this is the last character.

You're not yet being case-insensitive.

You want to do:

`/^e\d{8}$/i`

You will probably need to escape the `\`. The `/i` sets case-insensitive mode in sed and Vim, you might need to set that differently if you're using PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind explanation. It seems to be working I just need to run some tests on it :)

Comment: It's working except if I try "e123456789" so it has 9 numbers on the end it doesn't check that it seems... I spose I can just do a strlen() check anyway for the length. Unless there's a way in regular expressions to make sure it's only that length?

Comment: Are you sure you've got the `$`? You might need to escape it if you're using a `""` string.

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of `[a-z]`? That will match any lower case letter. Also, why do you have `\d{7}` if you want 8 digits? Try this:

```
^[eE]\d{8}$
```

The `[eE]` character class will match either an upper or lower case 'e'.

Answer (score 1):

Use may use this in your regular expression validation

[eE]{1}\d{8}

[eE] means only 'e' or 'E' is allowed

{1} means only 1st letter

\d{8} means next 8 letters will be digits ..

Hope, this may help you .